Johnson-Lindenstrauss type result for matrix factorization
The type of result I want is: given matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and error tolerance $\epsilon$, what is a lower bound on $k$ such that $\|A - UV\|_{??}\le \epsilon$, where $U \in\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$, $V\in \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$, and the norm is an arbitrary matrix norm.
I'm wondering if such a result exists, and if it does, a citation would be helpful.

The first result that should come to mind is the SVD & the Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem, for the spectral norm and the Frobenius norm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation
